# How to disable “Security Warning” window in Webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, security, https, browser

I'm using Webbrowser control to login to HTTPS site.
but I get popup "Security Warning":

[image: Security Warning window]

the codes below do n't work.why?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

where should i put these codes?

also there is another old thread in stackoverflow with a codeproject link.
it does not work too...

How can I disable this alert?

> i am using visual studio 2010 & .net 4...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property of `WebBrowser` control to `true`.

Comment: Kuba is referring to the [WebBrowser IE API control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), not the .NET controll

Comment: Sorry, this is `IWebBrowser2`'s interface field; named differently in .NET. I updated my answer. Plese un-downvote.